# Gitlab CI use export variable

Tags: gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

Is there any way to use an export variable, defined in the generic before_script:

```
before_script:
- export UPPERHASH=$(echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG | md5sum | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
```

into another job as a variable, because I am gonna use trigger but trigger does not allow to have any script, ex:

```
test variables:
  stage: test-variables
  variables:
    UPPERHASH_TEST1: $UPPERHASH
  trigger:
    project: "...\..."
```

I have tried multiple options but none of them is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work this way because `"test variables".variables` is processed before `before_script`

You only can refer to this variable in a `script:`

```
test variables:
  stage: test-variables
  script:
    UPPERHASH_TEST1=$UPPERHASH
    ... trigger other project from command line ...
```

Read here on how to trigger other project from command line

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html